# Bookmarklet to populate form?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a bookmarklet that would take the current URL that the person is on and pass it to a form on another website. The form is a POST and cannot be converted to a GET. Sounds similar to: [Bookmarklet to pass URL to form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024021/bookmarklet-to-pass-url-to-form-field) but that did not work for me (page did not change at all). The form I am trying to populate is very simple and only has 1 field that is requesting the URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the user to be taken to the website and see that URL pasted into the form?

Comment: Hi Bob -Still nothing is happening... I tried changing it to this and it doesnt even change the page its on when I click it: javascript:(function(f,s,n,o){XMLHttpRequest(f+encodeURICompnent(s),n,o)}('http://localhost/url',window.location,'form','width=300,height=200'));

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to imply that you could simply replace the one function call with the other; they do very different things.  But as I think about it, I'm not even sure XMLHttpRequest is the right approach.  It depends on your answer to my question above.  I think we need a clearer idea of what you want to happen.

Comment: Thank you for for the follow-up! Yes I would like the user to be taken to the form with the URL pre-populated in the field.